# Correct event to listen to before updating camera

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Updating camera and target based on dbid of a selected node. I am updating camera and target according to frag mesh retrieved with dbid and then moving to VR mode. Currently I have an event listeners GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT and OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT. Is there some other event that I should wait before running the code or updating the camera?

```
const nav = viewer.navigation;
const cam = nav.getCamera();
const it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;

let xPos, yPos, zPos;
it.enumNodeFragments(nodeId, (frag) => {
    const mesh = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer.model, frag);
    xPos = mesh.matrixWorld.elements[12];
    yPos = mesh.matrixWorld.elements[13];
    zPos = mesh.matrixWorld.elements[14];
}, false);
cam.position.set(xPos, yPos, zPos);
cam.target.set(xPos, yPos + 10000, zPos);

viewer.impl.sceneUpdated();
viewer.navigation.updateCamera();
document.getElementById("toolbar-vrTool").click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two events should ensure that your model is fully loaded and that your code can safely access the model hierarchy, this article may be useful: [Asynchronous viewer events notification](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/asynchronous-viewer-events-notification.html)

Comment: It seems the camera angle is correctly set after async.each for those two events, but when clicking VR mode on with: document.getElementById("toolbar-vrTool").click(); the camera jumps away from the model and does not keep the same camera angle. Can I somehow know when the WebVR extension is ready to be used?

Comment: Try the event Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT and check for "Autodesk.Viewing.WebVR" extension to be loaded